# path variable not getting added to path

Tags: macos, path

Following install instructions for llvm (after brew install llvm) it says I have to:

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

But after I do that and I check `echo $PATH` I only get:

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands`

So it's not there. How can I fix this.
(I hate setting paths, everyone says something else and Apple seems to love changing things so old posts are not valid anymore...)

Comment: Did you re-run your `.bash_profile` after modifying it?

Comment: How do I do that?